# Calculate number of weekend days records in array

Tags: java

I have a String Array which is contain dates that read from a CSV file.
Now I want to count **how many weekend days** are in that array. But in my array there are some dates are duplicated. Here shows part of the data that is containing in my Array.

> 12/2/2010
>   12/3/2010
>   12/5/2010
>   12/10/2010
>   12/5/2010
>   12/13/2010
>   12/14/2010
>   12/12/2010

In this data set **12/5/2010 is Sunday** (but there are two records) & **12/12/2010 is Saturday** (has One record). In output, I want to print number of weekend days in this array using **java**. Compared to this example the ***Answer should be 2***.

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("c:/cdr2.csv");
InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(fis);
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(isr);
while (bf.ready()) {
    String line = bf.readLine();
    String[] values=line.split(",");
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/d/yyyy");
    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(values[2]);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
}
```

Comment: This looks like a homeowrk question. Instead of asking us to do the work for you, please try to write some code and ask us to critique it.

Comment: Instead of an `Array`, put them into a `Set` then loop and print the weekdays. `Set`s do not allow duplicate entries.

Comment: i hav insert my java code here.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to write a method that determines if a given `Date` is a weekend or not:

```
public static boolean isWeekend(Date date) {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(date);
  int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
  return dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY || dayOfWeek == Calendar.SATURDAY;
}
```

Then, you need to define a [`DateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html), so that you can parse a date `String` into a `java.util.Date`. Finally, you can use a [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) to assure every weekend you find is not going to be duplicated:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  String[] dates = { "12/2/2010", "12/3/2010", "12/5/2010", "12/10/2010", "12/5/2010", "12/13/2010", "12/14/2010", "12/12/2010" };
  Set<String> weekends = new HashSet<String>();
  for (String dt : dates) {
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(dt);
    if (isWeekend(date)) {
      weekends.add(dt);
    }
  }
  System.out.println("There are " + weekends.size() + " distinct weekends."); // 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say you need to first remove duplicates and then check which of them are weekend days:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>( Arrays.asList(yourArrayOfDateStrings) );
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(yourDatePattern);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int weekendDays = 0;
for (String dateString : set) {
    calendar.setTime( df.parse(dateString) );
    int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.SATURDAY || dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
        weekendDays++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use java date, ever!
I agree with [Costi Ciudatu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/262683/costi-ciudatu), use a Set to remove duplicates.

:) please to send you teh codez using JodaTime

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeField;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Dates
{
    static String[] localTestDate = new String[] {"12/2/2010", "12/3/2010", "12/5/2010", "12/10/2010", "12/5/2010", "12/13/2010", "12/14/2010", "12/12/2010"};

    static DateTimeFormatter dateFactory = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/d/yyyy");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
//      final Set<DateTime> uniqueDates = generateUniqueDates(localTestDate);

        final Set<DateTime> uniqueDates = generateUniqueDates(readCommonSeparatedFile(args[0]));


        int numberOfWeekendDates = 0;
        for(DateTime date : uniqueDates)
        {
            if(isWeekend(date)) numberOfWeekendDates++;
        }

        System.out.println("There are " + numberOfWeekendDates  + " weekend days in your list.");
    }

    private static boolean isWeekend(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return (DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY == dateTime.dayOfWeek().get() || DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY == dateTime.dayOfWeek().get());
    }

    private static String[] readCommonSeparatedFile(final String fileName)
    {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

        String[] result = null;

        try
        {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);

            final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));

            while (bufferedReader.ready())
            {
                String line = bufferedReader.readLine();

                result = line.split(",");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            //log error some where

            throw new RuntimeException("aw, snap!");
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static Set<DateTime> generateUniqueDates(final String[] dates)
    {
        final Set<DateTime> dateTimes = new HashSet<DateTime>();

        for (String date : dates)
        {
            dateTimes.add(dateFactory.parseDateTime(date).toDateTime());
        }

        return dateTimes;
    }
}
```